# is there a working vmci example?

Tags: sockets, virtual-machine, vmware

I need a working VMCI socket example that does what UDP does, but without networking.  There are many good code fragments in the vmci_sockets.h code, but not a full working template to expand on.

I believe that the server should look as follows:

```
#include "vmci_sockets.h"
#define BUFSIZE 2048

int main() {
  int afVMCI = VMCISock_GetAFValue();
  if ((sockfd_dgram = socket(afVMCI, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    goto exit;
  }

  struct sockaddr_vm my_addr = {0};
  my_addr.svm_family = afVMCI;
  my_addr.svm_cid = VMADDR_CID_ANY;
  my_addr.svm_port = VMADDR_PORT_ANY;
  if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &my_addr, sizeof my_addr) == -1) {
    perror("bind");
    goto close;
  }

  if (getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &my_addr, &svm_size) == -1) {
    perror("getsockname");
    goto close;
  }

  if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, sizeof buf, 0,
               (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, &svm_size)) == -1) {
    perror("recvfrom");
    goto close;
  }

 close:
  return close(sockfd);
}
```

and for the client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "vmci_sockets.h"
#define BUFSIZE 128


int main() {
  int afVMCI = VMCISock_GetAFValue();

  int fd;
  struct sockaddr_vm addr;
  if ((fd = socket(afVMCI, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    return 1;
  }

  addr.svm_family = afVMCI;
  addr.svm_cid = VMADDR_CID_ANY;
  addr.svm_port = VMADDR_PORT_ANY;
  bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof addr);

  struct sockaddr_vm serveraddr;
  socklen_t svm_size = sizeof serveraddr;

  {
    int numbytes; char buf[BUFSIZE]; bzero(buf, BUFSIZE);
    strcpy(buf, "hello there\n");
    if ((numbytes = sendto(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0,
               (const struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, svm_size)) == -1) {
      perror("sendto error");
      goto close;
    }
  }

 close:
  close(fd);
  VMCISock_ReleaseAFValueFd(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

however, it's not working.  there is not much documentation, e.g., how to troubleshoot.  there is not information whether one can try both server and client within the same virtual machine for debugging purposes.

I tried to post to the vmware board, sent an email to their support, but no one seems to have a working example.  because this is not standard socketry, though it is similar socketry, it is and is not followable.

anyone have a working example?

Answer (score 0):

vmci is apparently not supported for vmplayer or vmware fusion.  this is what the vmware support people told me:

> I have been checking internally with our development team regarding
>   your request and incidentally could only generate interest if this was
>   a situation that is failing with vSphere. The final comment I have is
>   that we never meant to officially support this for VMware Fusion and
>   certain dependencies are on internal references only.
>
> Unfortunately, we do not have any such vmci example which can be
>   shared publicly when it comes to VMware Fusion.